# Mock awsEventStream

Tags: go, amazon-s3, goland

I have a function as below, I have tried mocking the aws s3 selectobjectcontentoutput but all in vain. I have even tried s3fice which says: Package s3iface provides an interface to enable mocking the Amazon Simple Storage Service service client for testing your code.

```
    func awsEventStream(resp *s3.SelectObjectContentOutput) string {

    ---

    return awsResponse

}
```

I am trying to write test case for the above as below, there are various methopds in s3 but I eed to mock only the method used in my main class.

```
    package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "testing"
)

type SelectObjectContentOutput struct {
    s3.SelectObjectContentOutput
}

func (m *SelectObjectContentOutput) EventStream(input *s3.SelectObjectContentInput) (*s3.SelectObjectContentOutput, error) {
    output := &s3.SelectObjectContentOutput{
        EventStream: nil,
    }
    return output, nil
}

func TestAwsEventStream(t *testing.T) {
    mockSvc := &SelectObjectContentOutput{}
    awsEventStream(&mockSvc.SelectObjectContentOutput)

}
```

Comment: The function under test uses `EventStream` as a field, but the mocked struct declares it as a method. What exactly are you trying to do? Also, you are passing the original object, not the mocked object to the function under test.

Comment: @BurakSerdar can you help with the code to mock `func awsEventStream(resp *s3.SelectObjectContentOutput) string {}` as i am not able to do so. I am getting struck and not able to proceed ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Not able to mock SelectObjectContentOutput. We are getting the EventStream as null.

When creating `s3.SelectObjectContentOutput`, you need to specify the `EventStream` attribute. From reading the [s3 SelectObjectContentEventStream docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#SelectObjectContentEventStream):

> For testing and mocking the event stream this type should be initialized via the NewSelectObjectContentEventStream constructor function. Using the functional options to pass in nested mock behavior.

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/#NewSelectObjectContentEventStream) also include example on how to use `NewSelectObjectContentEventStream`.

```golang
es := NewSelectObjectContentEventStream(func(o *SelectObjectContentEventStream){
    o.Reader = myMockStreamReader
    o.StreamCloser = myMockStreamCloser
})
```

For this question, we can ignore `StreamCloser` by setting it to empty ReadCloser.

Setting the `Reader SelectObjectContentEventStreamReader` will be trickier because it is an interface and from the look of it, s3 does not provide a direct way to construct the reader. Thought we can just create a type that implements it:

```golang
type stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader struct {
    StreamEvents <-chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent
    Error        error
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Events() <-chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent {
    return s.StreamEvents
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Err() error {
    return s.Error
}
```

Putting it all together:

```golang
func TestAwsEventStream(t *testing.T) {
    streamEvents := make(chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent, 3)
    eventStreamReader := stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader{
        StreamEvents: streamEvents,
        Error:        nil,
    }

    mockEventStream := s3.NewSelectObjectContentEventStream(func(o *s3.SelectObjectContentEventStream) {
        o.Reader = eventStreamReader
        o.StreamCloser = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(nil))
    })

    mockOutput := &s3.SelectObjectContentOutput{
        EventStream: mockEventStream,
    }

    streamEvents <- &s3.RecordsEvent{Payload: []byte("hello world")}
    streamEvents <- &s3.EndEvent{}
    close(streamEvents)

    got := awsEventStream(mockOutput)
    want := "hello world"

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %v, want %v", got, want)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @wijayaerick is appropriate and should cover around 60% of the code. But in case OP wants to cover the test case to 100% then he needs to traverse all the switch case statements. Below is my code that I have tried and it works as needed.

Few things that you would need to change is:

Make channel size to **3** `streamEvents := make(chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent, 3)`

Add `RecordsEvent`, `EndEvent` and `StatsEvent` to `streamEvents` as below:

```
statsEvent := &s3.StatsEvent{
    Details: &s3.Stats{
        BytesScanned:   aws.Int64(1024),
        BytesProcessed: aws.Int64(2048),
    },
}
streamEvents <- &s3.RecordsEvent{Payload: []byte("hello world")}
streamEvents <- &s3.EndEvent{}
streamEvents <- statsEvent
```

Your overall code will look like below:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "io"
    "testing"
)

type stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader struct {
    StreamEvents <-chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent
    Error        error
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Events() <-chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent {
    return s.StreamEvents
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Close() error {
    return nil
}

func (s stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader) Err() error {
    return s.Error
}

func TestAwsEventStream(t *testing.T) {

    type testCase struct {
        arg1 s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent
        want s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent
    }
    streamEvents := make(chan s3.SelectObjectContentEventStreamEvent, 3)
    eventStreamReader := stubSelectObjectContentEventStreamReader{
        StreamEvents: streamEvents,
        Error:        nil,
    }

    mockEventStream := s3.NewSelectObjectContentEventStream(func(o *s3.SelectObjectContentEventStream) {
        o.Reader = eventStreamReader
        o.StreamCloser = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(nil))
    })

    mockOutput := &s3.SelectObjectContentOutput{
        EventStream: mockEventStream,
    }
    statsEvent := &s3.StatsEvent{
        Details: &s3.Stats{
            BytesScanned:   aws.Int64(1024),
            BytesProcessed: aws.Int64(2048),
        },
    }
    streamEvents <- &s3.RecordsEvent{Payload: []byte("hello world")}
    streamEvents <- &s3.EndEvent{}
    streamEvents <- statsEvent
    close(streamEvents)

    got := awsEventStream(mockOutput)
    want := "hello world"

    if got != want {
        t.Errorf("got %v, want %v", got, want)
    }
}
```

[image]